# Child element effecting open/close toggle

Tags: javascript, html

I have created code for an open/close toggle filter by targeting the first li of the filter. For some reason, the children li's that are nested inside this are also closing the toggle when selected to filter the feed.

Please would someone be able to advise how to only target the parent li without the children li affecting the toggle from opening and closing?

Here is a link to the page with the filter. Please test the toggle and select a filter to see the issue that I am currently facing.

https://snapstaging.co.uk/coolkitnew/vans/

It may be worth noting that I don't want to target by class because I have multiple of these elements all with different classes.

```js
let filterBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.searchandfilter li ul')
let filterLi = document.querySelectorAll('.searchandfilter ul li')
let filterLiOpen = [];

filterLi.forEach((tag, index) => {
  tag.addEventListener('click', () => {
    filterLi[index].classList.toggle('active')
    if (!filterLiOpen[index]) {
      filterLiOpen[index] = true;
    } else if (filterLiOpen[index]) {
      filterLiOpen[index] = false;
    }

    console.log(filterLiOpen);
  })
})
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<div class="searchandfilter">
  <ul>
    <li class="sf-field-post-meta-vehicle_size">
      <h4>Size</h4>
      <ul data-operator="and" class="">
        <li class="sf-level-0"><label class="sf-label-checkbox">Large Van<span class="sf-count">(20)</span></label></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you select **all** the `li` elements in the DOM. To target only those which are children of the top level `ul`, not its descendants, use the child operator in your selector: `>`.

Also note that you can simplify the logic which toggles the boolean value you store in your array. Here's a working example:

```js
let filterLi = document.querySelectorAll('.searchandfilter > ul > li')
let filterLiOpen = [];

filterLi.forEach((tag, index) => {
  tag.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
    
    filterLiOpen[index] = !filterLiOpen[index];
    console.log(filterLiOpen);
  })
})
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<div class="searchandfilter">
  <ul>
    <li class="sf-field-post-meta-vehicle_size">
      <h4>Size</h4>
      <ul data-operator="and" class="">
        <li class="sf-level-0">
          <label class="sf-label-checkbox">
            Large Van
            <span class="sf-count">(20)</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sf-field-post-meta-vehicle_size">
      <h4>Size</h4>
      <ul data-operator="and" class="">
        <li class="sf-level-0">
          <label class="sf-label-checkbox">
            Medium Van
            <span class="sf-count">(10)</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>  
    <li class="sf-field-post-meta-vehicle_size">
      <h4>Size</h4>
      <ul data-operator="and" class="">
        <li class="sf-level-0">
          <label class="sf-label-checkbox">
            Small Van
            <span class="sf-count">(5)</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This query selector still targets the second level li element with class sf-level-0. To stop the queryselector including those lis, specifying that the list element has to be a descendant of a ul, that has to be a direct descendant of a .searchandfilter. The resulting query looks like .searchandfilter > ul > li

Comment: @PaulBollerman thank you - I misunderstood the goal of the OP's question. I edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for getting back to me. I really appreciate your help on this one.

I have implemented the code you have sent across, however, I forgot to mention there are multiple toggles but only the first toggle I opened stays open after the results update.

Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: Not sure why that would be happening - I edited the question to show an example of this working for multiple `li` elements. If your HTML doesn't match the above I'd suggest starting a new question including all the HTML